# Printing a statement in Java sesame

Tags: java, rdf, sesame

I am working on Java sesame. I started with a very little example following a tutorial. I am trying to build a simple statement as shown in the code. My problem is I do not know how to print out, for example, the subject or object of that statement. Could anyone please help me with this? Here is my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    ValueFactory factory = ValueFactoryImpl.getInstance();
    URI bob = factory.createURI("http://example.org/bob");
    URI name = factory.createURI("http://example.org/name");
    Literal bobsName = factory.createLiteral("Bob");
    Statement nameStatement = factory.createStatement(bob, name, bobsName);
    Statement typeStatement = factory.createStatement(bob, RDF.TYPE,FOAF.PERSON); 
}
```

I should use the following line:

```
model.filter(null, RDF.TYPE, FOAF.PERSON).subjects();
```

I should use a code like the one above but do not know how to define model and how to print out the statement or at least the subject. Your help is very much appreciated.

Comment: To the editor attempting to turn this into `public Example() { public static void main( ... ) ... } }`, the `public Example() { ... }` is a default constructor.  While the class as a whole would be named `Example`, it doesn't make any sense to declare a `main` method _inside_ a constructor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [javadoc for org.openrdf.Statement](http://openrdf.callimachus.net/sesame/2.7/apidocs/org/openrdf/model/Statement.html), you'd use [getSubject()](http://openrdf.callimachus.net/sesame/2.7/apidocs/org/openrdf/model/Statement.html#getSubject%28%29), [getPredicate()](http://openrdf.callimachus.net/sesame/2.7/apidocs/org/openrdf/model/Statement.html#getPredicate%28%29), and [getObject()](http://openrdf.callimachus.net/sesame/2.7/apidocs/org/openrdf/model/Statement.html#getObject%28%29).  As [pointed out in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19305339/printing-a-statement-in-java-sesame/19305655#comment28604410_19305655), the common implementation of Statement, [StatementImpl](http://openrdf.callimachus.net/sesame/2.7/apidocs/org/openrdf/model/impl/StatementImpl.html#toString%28%29), provides an implementation of [toString()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString%28%29) method so that you can even just print the Statement:

```
Statement s = /* ... */;
System.out.println( s );
```

Comment: it has such a method: http://openrdf.callimachus.net/sesame/2.7/apidocs/org/openrdf/model/impl/StatementImpl.html#toString()

Comment: The subject, predicate and object (which are all subtypes of `Value`) also all have a printable `toString()`.